# Two solutions for a collision which satisfy both conservation of momentum and energy. Which is correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum, energy-conservation

For the following problem, there are two sets of solution which appear to be equally valid:
v_car = 15.7 m/s, v_truck = 12.9 m/s and v_car = 12.3 m/s, v_truck = 15.2 m/s. How can I know which set of solutions is correct in such cases?

"A 1000-kg car traveling with an x component of velocity of +20 m/s collides head-on with a 1500-kg light truck traveling with an x component of velocity of +10 m/s.If 10% of the system's kinetic energy is converted to internal energy during the collision, what are the magnitudes of the final speeds of the car and truck?"

Comment: In general, there's no way to tell, but in this case you can. The car starts behind the truck, and the first solution would require the car to pass through the truck, which is impossible.

Comment: How do you know that the first set of solutions would require the car to pass through the truck? Is it because the final speed of the truck would be less than the final speed of the car?

Comment: That’s exactly right!

Answer (score 1):

To approach a more general form of this problem, let's skip the first step of your problem and just suppose you have already calculated:

Total momentum

$P' = m_1 v'_1 + m_2 v'_2$

Total energy

$E' = (1/2) m_1 v_1^{'2} + (1/2) m_2 v_2^{'2}$

Let $f = m_1/m_2$, and let's do our work in the center of mass frame where P=0. And instead of conserving energy E, I'll use a convenient constant C which is proportional to the center-of-mass energy, to save some factors of 2 and $m_2$. For ease, the velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$ represent center-of-mass velocities.

Momentum:

$f v_1 + v_2 = 0$, or $v_2 = -f v_1$

Energy:

$A = f v_1^2 + v_2^2 = f v_1^2 + f^2 v_1^2$

Now $v_1 = \pm \sqrt{\frac{A}{f+f^{2}}}$.

In the center-of-mass frame, it's obvious which root to choose based on the principle that @knzhou described in his comment, which is a little more general than it sounds! You choose the opposite sign of the initial velocity in the center-of-mass frame.

And then of course to solve your actual problem, you add back the center of mass velocity.